# How are literals as arguments for a CALL statement handled?

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to pass a string literal as an argument for a `CALL` statement.

```cobol
CALL "SOMEPROGRAM" USING "SomeStringLiteralArg"
```

I must define the argument as a linkage item in the called subprogram:

```cobol
LINKAGE SECTION.
 77 SOME-STRING-ARGUMENT PIC X(20).
```

That works, but when I pass a string literal shorter than 20 characters, the runtime starts complaining:

> Passed USING item (#1) smaller than corresponding LINKAGE item.

The given string literal must be 20 characters long. But there are reasons for me to pass a string literal as argument:

- <strike>I'm too lazy to define a temporary variable for each item I pass to a program.</strike> Having 100 'temporary' variables with different lengths in the working storage for each item I pass to a program, would make the program unnecessarily cluttered.

  ```cobol
  MOVE "ShortStrLit" TO SOME-TEMP-VAR
  CALL "SOMEPROGRAM" USING SOME-TEMP-VAR
  ```
- I also don't want to manually pad the string literal to match the required length of 20 characters:

  ```cobol
  CALL "SOMEPROGRAM" USING "shortStrLit         "
  ```

One of my questions is, or course: how can I pass a literal as an argument for a `CALL` statement? But, more importantly, the underlying question is: **how are literals passed as argument for a `CALL` statement handled?** For example, if I pass `9`, is it interpreted as a string with the contents "9", or is it compile-time converted to an integer?

---

I'm running MicroFocus ACUCOBOL-GT 9.2.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Compiler and OS, please. Full reference for the message (if there is a message number). Is it AcuCOBOL? http://community.microfocus.com/microfocus/cobol/extend_and_acucobol/w/knowledge_base/17365.item-passed-smaller-than-linkage-section-item.aspx

Comment: If you are going to be the only person, ever, working on that program, feel free to be as lazy as you like. Just don't come asking questions next time you look at the program. If not, if someone else is going to look at the program some time in the future, I'd advise against it. Your laziness is someone else's extra time down the line, every time someone looks at the program.

Comment: Literals scattered through the PROCEDURE DIVISION (beyond self-defining use, like ADD 1 TO COUNT-OF-RECORDS) are a bad idea. Why can't you use a VALUE clause on a data-definition. It's not really much typing, just master your editor.  Remember, or be aware, COBOL does not have "strings". Have a look at the documentation for the compiler you are using, literals in USING on a CALL are an area of "Extensions".

Comment: @BillWoodger *"Your laziness is someone else's extra time down the line, every time someone looks at the program."* I guess laziness is not the only thing involved. I'd rather use string literals than 100 temporary variables in the working storage.

Comment: So turn off the switch, use z-literals, and sort them out in the CALLed program. I really don't see how this is easier for you, but if it will only ever be you, have at it

Comment: Reading your edit now, can you give a clearer example of why you want to use so many different values to pass between the programs?  Why would you define them "temporary variables" as different lengths? That would defeat their use. MOVE ERROR-MESSAGE ( 70 ) TO MESSAGE-TO-REPORT CALL ... USING ... MESSAGE-TO-REPORT .... Is that the type of use you are after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two questions here:

First - How should I pass alphanumeric literals:

For `CALL some-cobol-prog USING "alphanumeric literal"` COBOL 2002 added the following:

```
LINKAGE SECTION.
 01 SOME-STRING-ARGUMENT PIC X ANY LENGTH.
```

If your compiler doesn't support it you're bound to either pad the literal or use a variable.

Second - Is a numerical literal interpreted as alphanumeric:

All compilers I've seen convert it to an integer - how and most important what type exactly depends on the compiler used...

Comment: `ANY LENGTH` – My compiler doesn't support it, but still, this is what I was looking for. (I guess I'm bound to use a variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Pic x any length is supported by isCobol.
isCobol support the compilation of acucobol sources.

I don't know if acucobol can support but, if so, you can define a string (java.lang.string) in the linkage section. This is also supported by isCobol.

```
working-storage section.
77 SOME-STRING-ARGUMENT PIC X(20).

linkage section.
77  this-string object reference j-string.

procedure dividion using this-string.
main.
    set some-string-argument to this-string.
```